# Search Function in HTML

Tags: java, html

How can I search text in HTMLDocument and then return the index and last index of that word/sentence but ignoring tags when searching..

**Searching:** stackoverflow
**html:** <p class="red">stack<b>overflow</b></p>

this should return index 15 and 31.

Just like in browsers when searching in webpages.

Comment: You can use this when manipulating or parsing html using java http://jsoup.org/

Comment: what class/method should I use in Jsoup or if there any jar lib.that can solve this?

Comment: Just want to make it clear first. Do you want to do this in Java or Javascript?

Comment: In java, I tagged this in java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in Java, here are rough example using Jsoup. But of course you should implement the detail so that the code can parse properly for any given html.

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
      + "<body><p class=\"red\">stack<b>overflow</b></p></body></html>";

String search = "stackoverflow";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String pPlainText = doc.body().getElementsByTag("p").first().text(); // will return stackoverflow

if(search.matches(pPlainText)){
    System.out.println("text found in html");

    String pElementString = doc.body().html(); // this will return <p class="red">stack<b>overflow</b></p></body>
    String firstWord = doc.body().getElementsByTag("p").first().ownText(); // "stack"
    String secondWord = doc.body().getElementsByTag("p").first().children().first().ownText(); // "overflow"

    //search the text in pElementString
    int start = pElementString.indexOf(firstWord); // 15
    int end = pElementString.lastIndexOf(secondWord) + secondWord.length(); // 31
    System.out.println(start + " >> " + end);

}else{
    System.out.println("cannot find searched text");
}
```

Comment: What if there is multiple line of stackoverflow?, like:
<b>stack</b>overflow
<i>stack</i><b>overflow</b>
<b>s</b>tack<b>overflow</b>

Comment: You have to read the API doc properly to achieve whatever things that you wanted. I just can give rough guide.